# Vertical bar for LaTeX interpreter

Tags: matlab, latex, symbols

What symbol to use for the vertical bar `|` in matlab latex strings?

When using `|` it becomes a horizontal dash and other option `\mid, \|, ...` all appear to result in an parse error.

I need it e. g. for absolute values like in `$ |x| $`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fig = figure(1);clf;
set(fig,'defaulttextinterpreter','latex');
title('$|x|$');
```

results in:
[image]

Comment: think I forgot the `$` symbol or so... At least it's working now